# Python NumPy, remove unnecessary brackets

Tags: python, numpy

In Numpy, Transposing of a column vector makes the the array an embedded array.
For example, transposing
`[[1.],[2.],[3.]]` gives `[[1., 2., 3.]]` and the dimension of the outermost array is 1. And this produces many errors in my code. Is there a way to produce `[1., 2., 3.]` directly?

Comment: I think you need to spend more time with the numpy essentials documentation.  Array shape, and various methods of `reshape` are an essential part of using `numpy`.  You should have all read about all the functions mentioned in the answer.  Changing between (3,1), (1,3) and (3,) shapes should be easy for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.flatten()`, `.ravel()`, `.reshape(-1)`, `.squeeze()`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the .flatten() method of a Numpy array to convert a multi-dimensional array into a one-dimensional array. In your case, you can simply call .flatten() on the transposed array to get the desired result:

```
import numpy as np
column_vector = np.array([[1.], [2,], [3,]])
flattened_array = column_vector.T.flatten()
print(flattened_array)
```

Output:

```
[1. 2. 3.]
```